# What should I do if I am missing salah due to having no place to pray in my office?

Tags: salat, work

Assalamualikum,
I am a girl and I am doing a job in a office. Because of that, I can't manage any time to perform my salah of Zuhr, 'Asr, Maghrib. Please  give me suggestion on doing salah at time in this case. And my office is located more than 13 km away from my home. Do I have to perform all of my fard and sunnah salah?

Answer (score 1):

It's not that ; you can't miss your prayers,   The other guy is saying you can make them up ; that the prophet missed etc...

Look i think this was a time of war and they overslept.You can only make up when you forgot or overslept.

https://islamqa.info/en/answers/111783/how-can-he-make-up-for-missed-prayers

If a person misses the prayer, one of two scenarios must apply:

1 –

He missed it for a reason, such as falling asleep or forgetting it. There is no sin on him in this case, but he has to make it up when he wakes up or remembers it.

It was narrated from Anas ibn Maalik (may Allaah be pleased with him) that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Whoever forgets a prayer, let him offer it as soon as he remembers, for there is no expiation for it other than that.” Narrated by al-Bukhaari (572) and Muslim (684); Muslim narrated an additional phrase: “or sleeps and misses it”.

Muslim also narrated (684): “If one of you sleeps and misses a prayer, or forgets it, let him offer the prayer when he remembers, for Allaah says ‘and perform As‑Salaah (Iqaamat‑as‑Salaah) for My remembrance’ [Ta-Ha 20:14].”

2 –

He missed the prayer with no excuse; rather he ignored it until the time for it ended, out of laziness and carelessness. This person is sinning according to the consensus of the Muslims, and has committed a major sin.

It is not valid for him to make it up according to the more correct of the two scholarly opinions, rather he has to repent and regret it, and resolve not to do that again, and he should do a lot of good deeds and offer a lot of voluntary prayers.
“Verily, As‑Salaah (the prayer) is enjoined on the believers at fixed hours”

Jabir reported: The Prophet, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “Verily, between a man and idolatry and unbelief is abandoning the prayer".

Make wudu from your home and go to work ; Also you can't pray while sitting if you can stand ; just go in the parking ; next to your car & pray

If there are womens in work ; it's haram to look ; don't look but if you can't avoid ,then you should leave that job;maybe necessity can be an excuse ;you don't have any job, if you leave you might suffer famine etc...

Also jummuah ; but if you live arround 800 meters from mosque then it's not compulsory;The max distance the adhan can reach whitout speaker, just voice is the distance, i think it's arround 800 meters or less; you should pray duhr instead  if live that far.

The Prophet, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “Verily, you will never leave anything for the sake of Allah Almighty but that Allah will replace it with something better.”

So do what's required; So pray because if you leave it for sake of people , or boss then it's a sin.You should pray for the sake of Allah

Source: Musnad Aḥmad 22565

Put a halal ringtone ; incase you don't have one; instead of music when someone calls you , put a ringtone of birds ;go to playstore ,also playstore in the homepage may contain some haram stuff; the ads in the app you install also ; If you turn off your wifi and use apps ,You won't have the ads

Answer (score 0):

When you are able to find time for prayer, pray all that you have missed. E.g if you came home at isha time and you missed zuhr asr and maghrib, you should start with zuhr, asr and maghrib before praying Isha. This is based on one of the hadith which talks about the prophet missing the fajr prayer and then when he and the companions woke up they prayed fajr. Please do research on this hadith as what i said is just what i remember.  It's a tough task which shouldn't be encouraged and one should find careers that enable them to pray on time. Better to build the world around islam rather than building islam around the world.

Comment: Praying on time is an order and not following it needs a permission or specific conditions  to do it otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

first you should find place for rest for 10 minute. if you can not find any place and office forbid praying in office you should pray in minimal movement. for example when a patient can't move limb, he (she) should move body until it possible and it is ok. You can never leave the prayer.

I hope your problem is solved.

Comment: First you should explain why a person who is able to move should pray like one who isn't ? This is more like a suggestion than an answer and it lacks any evidences.

Comment: @Medi1Saif sometimes you have special situation, like traveling with airplane or in environment that you limited to do some work, this is possible. i used patient example for noting that in worst case you cannot leave praying.

Answer (score 0):

If possible to join the prayers (Jamm), like Zuhar and Asr or Maghrib and Isha, then do like wise.

As you are not traveling, you can't shorten the prayers (Qasr).